# Anything I can do to improve usability of 'Solution Explorer' in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In solutions that contain a few different projects, I find myself constantly shuffling around in solution explorer looking for a particular file, when the tree gets expanded a little, there are often 4 'pages' of files to scroll through.

Does anyone have any tips for making solution explorer a bit more usable?

Perhaps Some 'collapse all folders' shortcut? or Some way of colour coding different projects?

I'm guessing theres not much that can be done, but thought I'd ask. I've got tons of horizontal screen space utilizing this in some way would be good.

Thanks

---

UPDATE
Regarding the right click context menus on solution and project nodes, here's what I have:

[image: Solution context menu]

[image: Project context menu]

Comment: Turns out "Collapse All" is added by ReSharper, which explains why you're not seeing it.  I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Get Visual Assist X from Whole Tomato.  it adds a number of hotkeys and nice features for opening files and finding stuff.

http://www.wholetomato.com/

Or upgrade to VS2010 if that's an option.  Visual Assist X is much cheaper :)

Comment: I'll check it out - thanks.  BTW, do you know if it's more usable in VS2010?

Comment: VS2010 has a hotkey that can open files/classes/etc in your solution (Ctrl+,)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
The ReSharper add-in adds a "Collapse All" menu item to the Solution Explorer's right click menu (it's way down at the bottom of the menu, and easy to miss).

Also, I really like ReSharper's [Find Usages](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Find_Usages) functionality, and do most of my solution level navigation that way.

Comment: Yep I highly recommend R#'s Cntl+T and Cntl+Shift+T for finding classes and files.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard works too, just type the first letter of the filename.